# How to prove the existence of n?

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

I do not understand the part in red which guarantees the existence of the n

could anyone please explain that part?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof claims that one can always pick an integer $n$ so that $b-2<n<b+2$, with $b=\frac{2f(x)}{\epsilon}$. The claim is true because we can pick $n=\lfloor b\rfloor$, where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ denotes the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) (i.e. integral part) of a real number.